# how to get any user's friends list in facebook by koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I'm using facebook api by Koala, I have a problem when I try to get another user's friend list (if I have the permission)

My code is:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@token)
@friends = @graph.get_connections("another user id", "friends")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@graph.get_connections('me', 'friendlists')
```

Comment: @siong1987 - It fetches only 4 friends instead of 200. How to fetch all friends?

Comment: @kpp facebook doesn't allow developers to access all friends in your friend list anymore.  only friends who are using the same app as you will show up in that list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using also facebook api by Koala...

But you get your facebook friends list with single line...

And did't worry about pagination etc...

```
@profile = @graph.get_object("me")
# perfectly get facebook friends count :)
@friends = @graph.get_connection("me", "friends",api_version:"v2.0").raw_response["summary"]["total_count"]
```